# System --> Preferences --> Visual Effects always boots to None

Tags: graphics, settings

In System --> Preferences --> Visual Effects it always says None.
When I change it to Extra or Custome it won't retain the setting, It returns back to None @ next boot. Ubuntu 14.04

Hardware:
GPU Integarated GeForce 8300
Memory:512 MB
Memory Interface:128-bit
3D-accelerated proprietary graphics driver for NVIDIA cards
NVIDIA Driver Version:  260.19.06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deactivate the current version of the driver and install an older version ( 196 series or 172 series). i had the same problem with my geforce 8400 gs in 10.04 and the 196 driver worked perfectly.